# Java Validation of Inheritance Objects

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

If I have a

```
  class parent(){}
  class child() extends parent{}
  class child2() extends parent{}
```

Then I have

```
  List<parent> // where i store all the child1 & child2 objects
```

Then I have a `Validator` service

```
RequiredValidator.validate(List<parent> classToValidate){
// here I use reflection to check for @Size @NotNull Annotations 
// i.e         
Field[] declaredFields = classToValidate.get(0).getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

Since child1 & child2 have different fields is it possible to check both children with one validator or do I need 2 validators, one for each class?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to validate.

Comment: Tangentially related: Your [class names should start with an uppercase letter](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411).